# Cypher syntax highlighting in a text area?

Tags: cypher, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to add syntax highlighting for a query box that accepts Cypher queries. Is there any shortcut already available ?

Answer (score 4):

I used [codemirror](https://codemirror.net/mode/cypher/index.html)
which was super easy to implement. First add the `codemirror.js` library and the `codemirror.css` file plus the `cypher.js` for the mode and also the cc file of the theme you want to use (in the example below the theme is `neo.css`). Then Create a textarea element in your html with `id="code"` and initialize it in your script:

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
    mode:'cypher',
    lineNumbers: true,
    theme: 'neo'
});
```

note that you can access the text by `getValue()` :

```
var query = editor.getValue();
```

and you can edit it by:

```
editor.setValue(data);
```